# WordPress loop (I think), I need the 5th to do something different

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I don't know PHP all that well so I hope I will be showing enough code when I ask this question. I have a part of my homepage that is going to show the latest 5 blog posts and so I set it up like this:

```
<?php
function get_latest_post_html() {
    $content = "";
    query_posts('showposts=5');
    while (have_posts()){
        the_post();
        $content .= "<p class='title'><a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a></p>\n" .
                "<p class='excerpt'><a href='" . get_permalink() . "'><img src='" . wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ) . "' class='rt-image img-left wp-post-image' style='max-width:175px;'/></a>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p><br/><hr/>";
    }
    wp_reset_query();

    return "<div class='latest-post'>\n$content\n</div>";
}

add_shortcode('get_latest_post', 'get_latest_post_html');
?>
```

It calls the last 5 posts just fine, but I don't want to have it display the `<hr/>` on the bottom of the 5th post.

Comment: Add a counter (`$i = 0`') before the loop, increment it each loop iteration (`$i++;`), and once it indicates the fifth loop (`if ($i == 5){ ... }`), suppress the `<hr />`. What's so complicated?

Comment: Read the first line. I DON'T KNOW PHP that well. I found this code from somebody else and knew enough to alter it to fit what I need minus the counter and all that

Comment: That's not PHP. That's **general, basic programming**. This approach works in ***any*** programming language, and is *Lesson 1* material.

Comment: And telling me this helps me how?

Comment: By informing you that, without a basic knowledge of the task you're trying to accomplish, you're just going to give yourself more work and grief in the long run. Learn to crawl before you attempt to fly.

Comment: Also, my initial comment *does* answer your question, if condescendingly.

Comment: Or go to a forum and get some real help when I won't be using this enough to have a long run.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a forum.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/192634)

Comment: Again, missing the main issue.

Comment: Honestly, what does it matter? You have one valid answer above, and two valid answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup some logic in your `while` loop to conditionally display the `<hr >`.

For example:

```
$i = 0;
while (have_posts()) {
  ++$i;
  the_post();

  // ...

  if ($i < 5) {
    $content .= '<hr />';
  }
}
```

**Note:** WordPress may not return 5 posts, so you should consider that path. I would also discourage string concatenation in tight loops. Refactor your code and use `echo`.

Comment: This did it. It only took you one post to answer it too. Who knew that could be done?

Answer (score 4):

Since you only need to get rid of the last `<hr/>`.

Try use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
So in your case, add this after while loop ends

`$content = substr($content, 0, -5)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function get_latest_post_html() {
    $content = "";
    query_posts('showposts=5');
    $i = 0;
    while (have_posts()){
    i++;
        if(i < 5){
        the_post();
            $content .= "<p class='title'><a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a></p>\n" .
                    "<p class='excerpt'><a href='" . get_permalink() . "'><img src='" . wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ) . "' class='rt-image img-left wp-post-image' style='max-width:175px;'/></a>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p><br/><hr/>";
        }
        else{
        $i = 0;
        //do something
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();

    return "<div class='latest-post'>\n$content\n</div>";
}

add_shortcode('get_latest_post', 'get_latest_post_html');
?>
```